Open MSWord File in .NET Maui
In my .Net Maui app, I'm trying to open a MS Word file, that I have added to the LocalApplicationData folder.  The MS Word file is loaded as an EmbeddedResource.  And I can see it in the folder.
However, when I run the app to view the file in MS Word, I get the following error msg.
"Sorry, we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted? (c:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Input.docs)"
But the full path that the file is added to is:
"C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Packages\com.companyname.mswordtest_yyyyyyyyy\LocalCache\Local\Input.docx"
Here is the Main.xaml.cs file with the code to add the file and Open and read the document.
using System.Reflection;

namespace MSWordTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private int count = 0;
        public static string inputPath { get; } = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Input.docx");

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (!File.Exists(inputPath))
            {
                var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(App)).Assembly;
                using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MSWordTest.Input.docx"))
                {
                    if (stream == null)
                    {
                        throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource 'Input.docx' not found in assembly.");
                    }

                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                        File.WriteAllBytes(inputPath, memoryStream.ToArray());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private async void OnWordClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tempPath = inputPath;

            //Open the Word file`

            await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest
            {
                File = new ReadOnlyFile(inputPath)
            });
        }
    }
}


Word can't read a file that is located in your app's local sandbox.  You need to copy it to a public folder

Thanks Jason, that pointed me in the right direction.  I've modified code to use public folders and app is working.

Changing the folder assignments to use a public folder solves the problem.
 public static string    destinationPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Input.docx");


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!File.Exists(destinationPath))
        {
            var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(App)).Assembly;
            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MSWordTest.Input.docx"))
            {
                if (stream == null)
                {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource 'Input.docx' not found in assembly.");
                }

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(destinationPath, memoryStream.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async void OnWordClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tempPath = destinationPath;

        //Open the Word file`

        await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest
        {
            File = new ReadOnlyFile(destinationPath)
        });
    }


Maybe you miss the topic Can I answer my own question? from the help center
